# Differences in NSDateComponents syntax?

Tags: swift, swift2, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I have been working on a clock app in Swift and with Xcode 6.3.2 the following code builds and runs just fine.

```
// Get current time
let date = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitSecond | .CalendarUnitNanosecond, fromDate: date)
let hour = components.hour % 12
let minute = components.minute
let second = components.second
let nanosecond = components.nanosecond
```

However when I load the same project up in Xcode 7.0 beta and make no changes whatsoever, I get an error on the calendar.components line.

```
Could not find member 'CalendarUnitHour'
```

I've looked at the documentation and all of the NSCalendarUnit constants are deprecated (in iOS 8.0 it says) but the method description for the components method still says to use them.

I've played around with other NSCalendarUnit auto-complete values but none produce working code and I can't find any recent examples online, perhaps because this is brand new.

Anyone know the new correct way to do this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Swift 2**

The `NSCalendarUnit` names have changed in Swift 2.

Also, now we have to pass these arguments in an OptionSet, like this:

```
let components = calendar.components([.Hour, .Minute, .Second, .Nanosecond], fromDate: date)
```

**Swift 3**

Many things have changed, according to the [Swift API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/).

Updated syntax:

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current()
let components = calendar.components([.hour, .minute, .second, .nanosecond], from: date)
```

**Swift 4**

`Calendar.current` is now a property, and `.components` has been renamed to `.dateComponents`. Otherwise it's the same as in Swift 3.

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second, .nanosecond], from: date)
```

Comment: Thanks! It was driving me batty. My code is 100% clean now. :-)

Comment: Another ridiculous change with no way to figure it out besides finding this SO question. Thanks Apple! (sarcasm).  Thanks Eric! (not sarcasm).

Comment: Due to name changes in Swift 2, it was giving me error "Type of expression is ambigous without more context".

Comment: Actually, it is not an array, but a set.

Comment: @lespommes: You could just read the release notes coming with Swift 2.

Answer (score 1):

They're now a new protocol.
OptionSetType

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_OptionSetType_Protocol/index.html

Comment: why the down vote. This is a common mistake people are making since moving to Swift 2. I'm giving you the technical reason why using the bar | doesn't work anymore!!