# How to scroll the entire section horizontally in CollectionView (Swift)

Tags: swift

I have few section in collectionView.
Currently header in top and scroll vertically.
But I want it to scroll horizontally and header in top remain sticky.
I assume it can be done through UICollectionViewFlow but not sure. 
Please help with example code in swift 2.0

**Current setting of collectionView in image below**
[image: Current setting of collectionView in image below]

**Calendar image**
[image]

Comment: Any solution (help) please!!!

Answer (score 0):

You must change the **scroll direction** in the attributes inspector to **horizontal**.