# How to calculate days to months, years, days in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I need to find months, years, days from given days. For example, 370 days, I need to convert to 1 year 0 month & 5 days. Days can be rounded off to the nearest month. For example, if days are less than 15, that should go to 0 month. If its more than 15 days, now that should go to 1 month

Comment: Which calendar? Which year? In the Gregorian calendar, a year can have 365 or 366 days. In the Islamic calendar, it can be  354 or 355 days. And there are many more ...

Comment: Do you need the calculation to be based on a specific date? For example, if you calculate 370 days from sometime in January, it will have to take February 29th into account. Basically, leap years = 366 days, non-leap years = 365 days.

Comment: Check this link, may be help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590316/how-do-i-find-the-number-of-days-in-given-month-and-year-using-swift

Comment: Even in the Gregorian calendar, 40 days can be 1 month and 9, 10, 11 or 12 days. – As you see, without more information, your problem is unclear.

Comment: @MartinR  I am looking for answer in Gregorian Calendar

Comment: Your task is still unclear to me, you did not address the above questions. Some *concrete* examples how different numbers of days in a month/year should be handled would be helpful.

Comment: number of days in each month can be diff, so also need a start date

Comment: Ok. Let me put it this way. If I said "how many months is 31 days?"  Then what would the answer be? Well 31 days from Jan 1st is Jan 31st. So only 1 month. But what if it was from Jan 15th? Well 31 days after that is the middle of Feb so that would be 2 months. Ok... what about from Jan 31st? 31 days after Jan 31st is somewhere close to the beginning of March so that's 3 months. None of these are wrong answers but they are all different. You cant just arbitrarily say a number of days. Calendars don't work that way.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you know starting and/or ending date, and not just distance between them, you can use this:

> ## **[date​Components(_:​from:​to:​)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/calendar/2292887-datecomponents)**
>
> *Returns the difference between two dates.*
>
> ### Declaration
>
> ```
> func dateComponents(_components: Set<Calendar.Component>, from start: Date, to end: Date) -> DateComponents
> ```
>
> ### Parameters
>
> > #### components
> >
> > Which components to compare.
> >
> > #### start
> >
> > The starting date.
> >
> > #### end
> >
> > The ending date.

Example:

```
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: <whatever calendar you need>)
let components: DateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.calendar, .year, .month, .day], from: startDate, to: endDate)
```

And then from `DateComponents` you get your `years`, `months` and `days` and what not.

Answer (score 1):

```
func numberOfDaysInCurrentYear() -> Int {
    let calendar = Calendar.init(identifier: .gregorian)
    let interval = calendar.dateInterval(of: .year, for: Date.init())!
    let days = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: interval.start, to: interval.end).day!
    return days
}
```