# Given year & month, how to check a particular day exists in that month

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I am trying to check if a particular day exists in a month or not. However unable to find anything of help. To give an example I tried below code in Playground;

```
var components = DateComponents()
components.month = 2
components.year = 2016
components.day = 30
components.calendar = Calendar.current

components.date
```

This gives the answer;

```
"Mar 1, 2016, 12:00 AM"
```

So what it does is it tries to manipulate with TimeZones and moves the needle. Hence I'm unable to find a way to check if a particular day exists in a given month & year. 
Can anyone please guide.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`DateComponents` has an `isValidDate` property, which you can use
for that purpose:

```
var components = DateComponents()
components.month = 2
components.year = 2016
components.day = 30
components.calendar = Calendar.current

print(components.isValidDate) // false
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I've a question here. Components.date is declared as Optional, but why it's shifting the date instead of returning nil.

Comment: @RameswarPrasad: `components.date` is nil  if `components.calendar` is not set. I don't know if there are other cases where it returns nil. Generally it "wraps around" to get a valid date. DateFormatter has as `isLenient` property to control that behaviour, but DateComponents does not have such a property.

Answer (score 0):

Lets break this down to -

> How to check number of days in a month-year?

Then your problem boils down to check if the given day is within the range [1, numDaysInMonthYear).

The code for above is this:

```
// Swift 2:
let range = calendar.rangeOfUnit(.Day, inUnit: .Month, forDate: date)
// Swift 1.2:
let range = calendar.rangeOfUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, inUnit: .CalendarUnitMonth, forDate: date)

let numDaysInMonthYear = range.length
print(numDaysInMonthYear) // 31
```

Credits: [How do I find the number of days in given month and year using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590316/how-do-i-find-the-number-of-days-in-given-month-and-year-using-swift/31591364#31591364)

Answer (score 0):

try this below method you can check the particular day exists in a month.

```
function checkDayIsExist(year:Int,month:Int,day:Int) -> Bool {

   let dateComponents = DateComponents(year: year, month: month)
   let calendar = Calendar.current
   let date = calendar.date(from: dateComponents)!

   let numberOfDays = calendar.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: date)!
   return numberOfDays.count >= day
}
```

Call by

```
print(checkDayIsExist(year:2017,month:7,day:31)) // true
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check by using `NSDateFormatter / DateFormatter`

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MM yyyy"

let dateString = "30 02 2017"

if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
{
  print("Date \(date)")   
}
else
{
  print("Date not existed")
}
```

You can change the date formatter's dateFormate based on your input string.